# Изменение объекта

Tags: c#

```
 public class LinkedListNode<T>
{
    public LinkedListNode(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public LinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; } 
}

 public class LinkList<T>
{
    private LinkedListNode<T> _head;
    private LinkedListNode<T> _tail;

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> node = new LinkedListNode<T>(value);

        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = node;
            _tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            _tail.Next = node;
            _tail = node;
        }          
    }     
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {   
        LinkList<int> instance = new LinkList<int>(){};

        instance.Add(5);//1-й элемент списка
        instance.Add(10);//2-й

    }
}
```

После добавления первого элемента срабатывает условие `if (_head == null)`,
затем добавляется второй элемент,выполняется `else` и срабатывает `_tail.Next = node` при этом изменяется не только `_tail.Next`,но и `_head.Next`,почему?

Comment: Я ни разу не C# программист, но есть у меня подозрение, что раз у вас `_head = node; _tail = node;` эти две переменные указывают на один объект

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что _tail и _head указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти. Соответственно, при добавлении второго элемента нет разницы между `_head.Next = node` или `_tail.Next = node`.